# ¿Como quitar los espacios entre divs e inputs?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo el siguiente problema, no puedo eliminar los espacios que tengo entre dos divs e inputs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy utilizando `bootstrap` el código para los `inputs` es el siguiente:

```
<input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 m-0" title="pendiente">
```

La intención es hacer que estos `inputs` parezca una tabla

```
 <div class="container-with-scroll-horizontal square-corners no-shadow" id="tablePresupuestos">
    <div class="row-with-scroll-horizontal">
        <div class="col-3 p-1">Desarrollo / Ubicación</div>
        <div class="col-3 p-1">Insumos</div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-8 col-md-4 p-1">Enero</div>
        <div class="row-with-scroll-horizontal">
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 p-1">Sem - 1</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 p-1">Sem - 2</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 p-1">Sem - 3</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 p-1">Sem - 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-with-scroll-horizontal">
        <div class="autocomplete p-0 col-3" style="display: block;">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm name-development" title="Desarrollo o ubicación">
            <div id="autocomplete-items1" class="autocomplete-items autocomple-items-1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="autocomplete col-3 p-0">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm name-insumos" id="myInput" title="nombre de los insumos">
            <div id="autocomplete-items2" class="autocomplete-items"></div>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 m-0" title="pendiente">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 m-0" title="pendiente">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 m-0" title="pendiente">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-2 col-2 col-md-1 m-0" title="pendiente">
    </div>
    <div id="finTabla"></div><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Este el css

```
 .square-corners input{
    border-radius: 0!important;
    }

.no-shadow input:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.container-with-scroll-horizontal {
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.row-with-scroll-horizontal > * {
    display: inline-block!important;
    float: none;
}
```

el problema es el de la siguiente ruta https://codepen.io/epifanioperezr/pen/jQRboZ

Comment: prueba quitando `m-0`; aunque si quieres realizar una tabla, deberías usar el tag `<table></table>` para ello no?

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, ya intente con el m-0, para este caso no me conviene usar un table

Comment: Entiendo :).. Te funciono quitando el atributo `m-0`?

Comment: No, no me funciono, ademas cuando selecciono los input pareciera como si hubiera en espacio en medio de ellos

Comment: Puedes incluir toda la estructura de tu `HTML`? con los **divs** incluidos?

Comment: qué versión de bootstrap es?

Comment: la cosa con los `input` es que por defecto tienen `display :inline-block` y por defecto `inline-block` tiene un espacio consistente entre sus elementos que no puedes eliminar, puedes agregarles `float left`

Comment: muchas gracias @LPZadkiel el comentario tuyo acerca de `display :inline-block` me ha resuelto varios problemas en  estos año, en verdad esa es la solución más optima

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podría servirte algo así:

```css
input {
  display: block !important; 
  padding: 0 !important; 
  margin: 0 !important;  
  width: 100% !important; 
  border-radius: 0 !important; 
  line-height: 1 !important;
}

td {
  margin: 0 !important; 
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <table style="border:none;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Desarrollo / Ubicación</th>
        <th>Insumos</th>
        <th>Enero</th>
        <th>Sem - 1</th>
        <th>Sem - 2</th>
        <th>Sem - 3</th>
        <th>Sem - 4</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Si bien, tuve que agregar otros estilos, se acerca un poco a lo que podrías necesitar.

Nos comentas